# Merge columns from multiple files in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need help merging the content of two pipe delimited files.

#### I have

**file1**

```
a|b|1|test|0
v|3|r|rest|4
5|4|a|two|3
3|5|r|help|4
```

**file2**

```
01May2014
```

### I want

**file3**

```
a|b|1|test|0|01May2014
v|3|r|rest|4|01May2014
5|4|a|two|3|01May2014
3|5|r|help|4|01May2014
```

Any help, especially ones involving the "awk"statement, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWK language, here's one way:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { r = $0; next } { print $0, r }' OFS="|" file2 file1
```

Results:

```
a|b|1|test|0|01May2014
v|3|r|rest|4|01May2014
5|4|a|two|3|01May2014
3|5|r|help|4|01May2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you know that there is just one line in `file2`, you could use:

```
awk -v extra=$(<file2) -e '{ OFS="|"; print $0, extra }' file1
```

Or in `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/$/|'"$(<file2)"/' file1
```

Both of these avoid processing two files in the main program (`awk` or `sed`); they let the shell do the work on `file2` and use the results of that work.

The `$(<file2)` notation is equivalent to, but more efficient than, `$(cat file2)` and is a Bash extension.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how robust or generic it needs to be, something like this could work:

```
sed "s/$/|$(cat file2)/" file1 > file3
```

This of course assumes file2 is just a single line to be concatenated on to the end of each line in file1.  The sed command s/foo/bar/ replaces all occurrences of "foo" with "bar". In this case, it replaces the end of a line ("$") with | followed by the output of the command "cat file2".  It does this for file1, redirecting the output into file3.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works but it appends starting from a new line for example line one(1) will have the original value and line two(2) will have the appended value.

Comment: This works `sed "s/.$/|$(cat file2)/" file1 > file3`